# Передвинуть объект в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Помогите пожалуйста. Нужен скрипт для 2D игры в Unity. Нужно чтобы при ОДИНОЧНОМ нажатии кнопки персонаж передвигался на n-количество влево (или вправо в зависимости от кнопки). Главная проблема в том, чтобы персонаж не телепортировался, а плавно перемещался.

Comment: Обновила ответ в соответствии с Вашим уточнением

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать это, например, так. Повесить на Вашего игрока (который является  `Rigidbody2D`) скрипт `PlayerController`, в котором прописать такой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); // инициализируем объект игрока
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //указываем движение персонажа по горизонтальной оси, в зависимости от указанной Вами скорости, и учитывая направление
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y); 
    }
}
```

В Inspector-е не забудьте указать значение переменной `speed` (например, 4). От величины `speed` будет зависеть шустрость Вашего персонажа.

Гляньте этот [туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vhMXhic2S8), тут очень толково всё объясняется. Можно добавить возможность прыжков, поворота персонажа при ходьбе в разные стороны, анимацию хождения и прыжков...

**UPDATE**
С учетом уточнения о том, что персонаж должен плавно перемещаться при одноразовом нажатии на заданную кнопку, код меняется. В таком случае логично использовать `Couroutine`. Например, так.

```
void Clicked(bool left)
{
     Vector2 relativeLocation = new Vector2(5, 0); 
     if (left) relativeLocation = new Vector2(-5, 0);
     /* 5 - произвольное число, "расстояние", на которое должен перемещаться персонаж. 
     Можно вынести в public-переменную и играться*/
        
     Vector2 targetLocation = new Vector2(rb.transform.position.x, rb.transform.position.y) + relativeLocation;
     float timeDelta = 0.05f; // время, за которое персонаж должен совершить перемещение
     this.StartCoroutine(SmoothMove(targetLocation, timeDelta));
}

IEnumerator SmoothMove(Vector3 target, float delta)
{
     float closeEnough = 0.2f;
     float distance = (rb.transform.position - target).magnitude;

     WaitForEndOfFrame wait = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
     while (distance >= closeEnough)
     {
         transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(rb.transform.position.x, rb.transform.position.y), target, delta);
         yield return wait;
         distance = (rb.transform.position - target).magnitude;
     }
     rb.transform.position = target;
}
```

Тогда в `FixedUpdate()` будет такой код (в примере я использовала кнопки A и S для управления персонажем):

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) Clicked(false);
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) Clicked(true);
}
```

Тут ключевой метод - `Lerp`. Он производит линейную интерполяцию между двумя точками, поэтому движение объекта плавное.